# Creating a function that accepts a string & creating a function that accepts a boolean value and a string

Tags: string, function, if-statement, boolean

Create a function **makePlans** that accepts a string. This string should be a name. The function **makePlans** should call the function **callFriend** and return the result. **callFriend** accepts a boolean value and a string. Pass in the **friendsAvailable** variable and name to **callFriend.**

Create a function **callFriend** that accepts a boolean value and a string. If the boolean value is true, **callFriend** should return the string **'Plans made with NAME this weekend'**. Otherwise it should return **'Everyone is busy this weekend'.**

So far this is what I have come up with:
let friendsAvailable = true;

```
function makePlans(name) {
  // INSERT CODE HERE
  return `Plans made with ${name} this weekend`;
                
}

function callFriend(bool, name) {
  // INSERT CODE HERE  
  if (callFriend = true); {
    return 'Plans made with ${name} this weekend';
  } else (callFriend = false)  {
    return "Everyone is busy this weekend";
  }
}
// Uncomment these to check your work!
 console.log(makePlans("Mary")) // should return: "Plans made with Mary this weekend'
 friendsAvailable = false;
 console.log(makePlans("James")) //should return: "Everyone is busy this weekend."
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what to correct, The console tells me there is a syntax error: unexpected token 'else'

Comment: I think it's the semicolon after `if (callFriend = true);` that's your problem.

Also, generally it's helpful to tag your question with which language you're using when you post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `;` in the line `if (callFriend = true);`.

The `;` effectively terminates the `if` condition. The braces after it are just treated as an encapsulated block meaning when the compiler gets to the `else` it's confused since it thinks the previous `if` statement is finished.

Answer (score 2):

**`

```js
let friendsAvailable = true;

function makePlans(name) {
  // INSERT CODE HERE
  return callFriend(friendsAvailable, name);
}

function callFriend(bool, name) {
  // INSERT CODE HERE
  if (bool == true){
    return `Plans made with ${name} this weekend`
  } else if (bool == false) {
    return "Everyone is busy this weekend"
  }
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
console.log(makePlans("Mary")) // should return: "Plans made with Mary this weekend'
friendsAvailable = false;
console.log(makePlans("James")) //should return: "Everyone is busy this weekend."
```

`**

Answer (score 0):

```
So I managed to put 


    let friendsAvailable = true;

function makePlans(name) {
  // INSERT CODE HERE

  return callFriend(friendsAvailable, name);
            
}

function callFriend(bool, name) {
  // INSERT CODE HERE  
  if (bool) {
    return (`Plans made with ${name} this weekend`);
  } else  {
    return "Everyone is busy this weekend";
  }
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
console.log(makePlans("Mary")) // should return: "Plans made with Mary this 
weekend'
friendsAvailable = false;
console.log(makePlans("James")) //should return: "Everyone is busy this weekend."
```